# Angular 6 canActivate issue in deployment

Tags: angular6

I have implemented `AuthGuard` in angular. The code uses component name to do the validation:

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {


constructor(private permissionService: PermissionService, private router: Router) {}

canActivate(
next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

  let component = next.component;

  let componentName = component["name"];

  let params = next.params;

  return this.permissionService.checkPermission( componentName, params);

  }

}
```

This code works in `ng serve` testing. But when build and deploy the application in web server,  `component["name"]` is not the original component name, instead gives jung.

Any idea on this isue? Thanks.